# SecurityConfig Java file error

Tags: java, xml, spring, restful-authentication, spring-java-config

I am new to Spring and trying to create authentication for RESTful API using Spring. I am getting the following error, how can I resolve this?

StackTrace:

```
Error creating bean with name 'webConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.base")
public class WebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().
        withUser("temporary").password("temporary").roles("ADMIN").and().
        withUser("user").password("userPass").roles("USER");
    }

     @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
            http
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/foos").authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .and()
            .logout();
        }

}
```

MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java

```
 @Component
public class MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);

        if (savedRequest == null) {
            clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
            return;
        }
        String targetUrlParam = getTargetUrlParameter();
        if (isAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl()
                || (targetUrlParam != null && StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(targetUrlParam)))) {
            requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);
            clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
            return;
        }

        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }

    public void setRequestCache(RequestCache requestCache) {
        this.requestCache = requestCache;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@EnableWebSecurity`  for web security configuration

Split the `WebConfig` from the `WebSecurityConfig` to different classes.